# Vim edit file over http

Tags: http, vim

I am trying to do this:

```
vim http://mysite.com/x.html
```

I have `chmod 777` on the file to make sure full access is granted, I can open the file without a problem,
but when I tried to save the edit, there prompted an error:

```
"http://mysite.com/x.html" E212: Can't open file for writing
```

Answer (score 0):

You (obviously) can't upload that file to the server via http.

Use ssh/scp or ftp.

See `:help netrw`.

Answer (score 0):

`http` is the wrong protocol here. This makes for a good read: http://www.w3.org/blog/2008/10/understanding-http-put/ - the HTTP 'verbs' (PUT, POST, GET etc.) do not dictate how the server is going to handle the request you send. In fact HTTP "defines the intended semantics of the communication... (but) does not define how either side fulfills those expectations".

You could quite easily run

```
vim http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476683/vim-edit-file-over-http
```

but you won't be able to edit this page.

See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Editing_remote_files_via_scp_in_vim for working on files via ssh / ftp.